# Why wouldn't a category menu be displaying on a magento theme?

Tags: magento, customization, magento-1.7

I'm trying to set up a dynamic menu in a Magento store (v1.7 community edition with the hellowired theme) and can't figure it out why on earth is not being displayed on my home page.

I don't know if there's a mistake in the call on the .phtml files of the theme or if I'm missing some configuration. I have already configured it as described in the theme's documentation and set several products and I'm still not seeing the menu displayed.

If I hard code the category call, it works fine, but it's just a workaround since I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: Have you applied your design change from System->Design ? Are you using more than one root category ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns Out for the theme I was using (The Hellowired one, but it appears to apply to several) it was required to set-up all categories under the Default Category. This question was answered to me by an admin of the theme site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the flag `Is Active` and `Include in Navigation Menu` set to "YES" from admin panel under `General Information` Tab in Catalog->Manage Categories.

Comment: thanks Amit. Yeah, they are both set active and included in navigation menu but nothing displays

Comment: that category is root category or child category ?
If your root category is set to Active only then you can display child category.

Comment: In fact I would like to place several categories in the navigation menu in a line @Amit Chaudhary, thanks for your following.
[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12878850/magento-q_cat-flags.PNG)

Comment: I realised i didnt answer your question. I was talking about root categories, several root categories. Thanks @AmitChaudhary